# Orchard CMS Database Part vs PartRecord

Tags: orchardcms

In Orchard database, there is tables name ending with 'Record' and other with 'PartRecord'.

What is the logic behind that?

Answer (score 1):

The tables for a part record should end in "PartRecord". If a table ends in "Record" without "Part" in front, it shouldn't map to a part record. For example, "ContentItemRecord" is a record, but not a part record. ContentItem is not a part.

Answer (score 0):

Content part records are record classes that store content part data in the database.

While its not mandatory to have a part **and** a part record, it is a good practice to split the real data model (the record) from the model you are going to manipulate and/or read (the part).

The naming of the tables are all up to the module developers, but usually they are postfixed with PartRecord.

Looking at my Orchard database, I do not see any tables ending with Part. My guess is that with your application they are custom modules or third party modules, where the developer chose to postfix it with just Part.

Comment: Hi, I have a lot of tables ending with 'Part' that are not from a custom modules like "Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord".

Comment: "Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord" doesn't end with "Part"?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand then. Your question is why tables end with part, but they actually don't. Is your question really why some tables end with part record and others record?

Comment: You're right. I will change my question. I want to know the difference between "PartRecord" and "Record".