# Orchard CMS module no values from Editor

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I've created my first simple module but for some reason my editor doesn't seem to be getting any values from the form.

The code is basically a slight modification on the Maps module example. (I've trimmed usings and whatnot for brevity.) The example is here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part

EDIT: I narrowed it down to my bool and DateTime properties. If I only use strings and ints my module works as expected. I have looked at other migrations in my modules directory and they use the generic Column method. I tried this, but still cannot get it to work.

Model:

```
namespace Maps.Models
{
    public class MapRecord : ContentPartRecord
    {
        public virtual int SenderId { get; set; }
        public virtual int RecipientId { get; set; }

        public virtual string Subject { get; set; }
        public virtual string Body { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

        public virtual bool Read { get; set; }
        public virtual int ReplyTo { get; set; }
    }

    public class MapPart : ContentPart<MapRecord>
    {
        [Required]
        public int SenderId
        {
            get { return Record.SenderId; }
            set { Record.SenderId = value; }
        }

        [Required]
        public int RecipientId
        {
            get { return Record.RecipientId; }
            set { Record.RecipientId = value; }
        }

        [Required]
        public string Subject
        {
            get { return Record.Subject; }
            set { Record.Subject = value; }
        }

        [Required]
        public string Body
        {
            get { return Record.Body; }
            set { Record.Body = value; }
        }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Timestamp
        {
            get { return Record.Timestamp; }
            set { Record.Timestamp = value; }
        }

        [Required]
        public bool Read
        {
            get { return Record.Read; }
            set { Record.Read = value; }
        }

        [Required]
        public int ReplyTo
        {
            get { return Record.ReplyTo; }
            set { Record.ReplyTo = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Migrations.cs

```
public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl {

        public int Create() {
            // Creating table MapRecord
            SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("MapRecord", table => table
                .ContentPartRecord()
                .Column<int>("RecipientId")
                .Column<int>("SenderId")
                .Column<string>("Subject")
                .Column<string>("Body")
                .Column<DateTime>("Timestamp")
                .Column<bool>("Read")
                .Column<int>("ReplyTo")
            );

            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
                typeof(MapPart).Name, cfg => cfg.Attachable());

            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your migration look like?

Comment: @devqon I have added the migration to the question.

Comment: Have you added a content handler?

Comment: Yes, but it's not changed from the sample. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: When you say reset your Orchard, you deleted the App_data folder?

Comment: Yes, that was the solution Bertrand suggested on another post.

Comment: Try renaming your record to `MapPartRecord` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407083/orchard-cms-database-part-vs-partrecord)

Comment: I renamed the class MapPartRecord but it failed. I then updated the table name to be MapPartRecord in the migration and still no dice.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the DateTime and bool properties. For some reason they are breaking it. See updated Migrations.cs and model class.

Answer (score 0):

If this is similar to the example there could be two possible issues. 1) Maybe you haven't added the placement file. If the migration worked and there is no placement file then you won't see the data. 2) Another possible solution if the migration is failing would be that it doesn't have the correct DataTypes for **bool** and **DateTime**. Instead try ***DBType*.Boolean** and ***DBType*.DateTime**. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Originally I had the migrations as .Column("name", DBType.DateTime) etc, but that didn't work so I tried using the generic method instead. Still no dice. Thanks for the idea. I still haven't resolved this - I just moved on and will come back and try and figure it out later. It's more a proof of concept for me rather than something serious.